# How to upgrade kubespray kubernetes cluster container runtime?

Tags: kubespray

What is the process to upgrade an existing kubernetes cluster using a specific container runtime (ie: Docker) to another (ie:  Containerd)

Will changing the runtime in the Hamel and doing an uograde_cluster be sufficient?

Presumably this will be asked more frequently, it may make sense to document a procedure given that kubernetes 1.20 deprecates Docker.

Comment: Very very good question. Did you find out something in the past months?